# Datatable search filter

Tags: datatable

I have datatable like these

```
var table = $("#tbl_multipoinfo");
        var filter = $('.form-filterpo');
        var target = table.attr('data-table');
        $("#pideldate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'                                    
        });

        var oTable = table.on( 'processing.dt', function ( e, settings, processing ) {
                if (processing) {
                    $(this).find('tbody').addClass('load1 csspinner');
                } else{
                    $(this).find('tbody').removeClass('load1 csspinner');
                };
            } ).DataTable({
                "ajax": host+'datatable/'+target,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
                "bFilter" : true,
                "scrollY":        "200px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "paging":         false,
                "paging":         false,
                "ordering": false
            });
```

But my problem is i'm stuck on seacrh filter (functional DATATABLE), even i'm trying typing anything still wont work at all, i try use code like these

```
        $('.dataTables_filter input').unbind().keyup(function(e) {
             var value = $(this).val();
             if (value.length>0) {
                oTable.search(value).draw();
            } else {     
                //optional, reset the search if the phrase 
                //is less then 3 characters long
                oTable.search('').draw();
            } 
        });
```

But it wont let me filtered, is still same result. I might missing something, so can anyone help me these issue??

Comment: When you have serverside the serverside script must take care of filtering.

Comment: @davidkonrad : Nvm i found a solution, i remove the serverside. And is work perfectly. Tq for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, i change my code on Datatable

on

```
"bServerSide": true,
```

i removed it, and i put another input like these

```
<form class="form-filterpo" role="form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 pull-right" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                            <label>PO : </label>
                            <input id="fPono" class="form-control input-sm" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

And add these on jquery (same at jquery my table)

```
$('#tbl_multipoinfo_filter').remove();

        filter.find('#fPono').keyup(function(){
            var fPono = $(this).val();
            oTable.columns(1).search(fPono).draw();
        });
```

And it work perfectly.

NB : If u do server side try put query instead on where, for my case i don't use query cause my query instead temporary need check list on each row.